# Uncaught SyntaxError in my JS code while calling the function

Tags: javascript, xslt, syntax-error

I am trying to write a JS function for my xslt but i am getting `'' string literal contains an unescaped line break` this error on line `number[cnt] = '<xsl:value-of select="termsandconditions" />';` while calling my JS function. I am not sure why i am getting this error. Any help or suggestions are welcome.Thanks!!

`Script`

```
function myFunction() {
                    var number = new Array();
            cnt=0;
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//faml/response/termsandconditonsresponsedto/terms_conditons">
                    <xsl:for-each select="//faml/response/termsandconditonsresponsedto/terms_conditons/tandcdto">       
                        number[cnt] = '<xsl:value-of select="termsandconditions" />';
                        alert(number[cnt]);
                        </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            
                        document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = number[cnt];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is Javascript executed by modern browsers then use the back tick:

```
number[cnt] = `<xsl:value-of select="termsandconditions"/>`;
```

I don't think that IE supports that. If you need IE support, then write XSLT to escape any line breaks and single quotes in `termsandconditions`, easy in XSLT 2 and later with `replace`, more tedious in XSLT 1, where you need a named template or support for an extension function.